# SingleEmailMessage not working

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I tried this code in anonymous apex and I did not get an email.

```
 List<String> oid_updated = new List<String>{'1','2','3','4','5'};
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'XX@gmail.com'};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setReplyTo('noreply@XXsp.com');
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
    mail.setSubject('SOA Impl Opp Report ');
    mail.setBccSender(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    mail.setPlainTextBody(String.ValueOf(oid_updated));
    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results= Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    System.debug(results);
```

But when I modified the code slightly I started receiving the email.

```
List<String> oid_updated = new List<String>{'1','2','3','4','5'};
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'XX@gmail.com'};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setReplyTo('noreply@XXsp.com');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
mail.setSubject('SOA Impl Opp Report ');
mail.setBccSender(false);
mail.setUseSignature(false);
mail.setPlainTextBody(String.ValueOf(oid_updated));

Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail }); //CHANGE
```

If I am not able to get the results via `Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results`, then this will not allow me to determine whether the email has been sent successfully or not.

Can someone explain why the first code snippet is not working ?

Comment: Is the only difference that you don't get the Messaging.SendEmailResult array in code and debug it out? Maybe get the results and then iterate over them and assert that [`isSuccess()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_sendemailresult.htm#apex_Messaging_SendEmailResult_isSuccess) returns true.

Comment: There is no issue with first block of code. I just run it with my email id and it worked just fine. Most probability you have not entered  proper email id.